# Group the results from two query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

i spent around 4 hours on this but i couldnt find answer, i want the result like

Rejects

somefilename1.txt - Rejected (and if no file then No from else expression(No - Invalid) - Query 1)
somefilename2.txt - Previous (and if no file then No from else expression(No - Valid) -Query 2)

I dont understand what do i do, do i use union all or case expression. plz help me with this.

QUERY1:

```
if exists (select NULL from table1 where Column1 = 'File1')
    select distinct Column1 +'-'+ 'Rejected' as 'Rejects' from table1
    where Column1 = 'File1'
else 
    select 'No' as 'Invalid'
```

QUERY2:

```
if exists (select NULL from table1 where Column1 = 'File2')
    select distinct Column1 +'-'+ 'Previous' as 'Rejects' from table1
    where column1 = 'File2'
else 
    select 'No' as 'valid'
```

Thanks

Comment: You've chosen a wrong dialect for this site.

Comment: i am sorry. i am new to this.

Comment: Neo, welcome to Stack Overflow - just a tip, "PLZ HELP ME WITH THIS" is really not a good title - it will cause people to downvote your question as has already happened.  Just try "Group the results from two queries" or something...  You can edit it, so no problem.

Comment: i apologize for not putting question properly. thanks guys. i am gonna keep in mind next time. thanks.

Comment: Please indicate the requirements with a little bit more clarity. Can you explain in words what the code should do and roughly what it should be checking. Is it a function with one input, or do you put multiple inputs (ie. multiple filenames).

Comment: yes its multiple filenames and first and second queries gives the different txt files or if there is no txt then No from else. let me know if i explained it. i will try my best.

Comment: @Neoooooo, are you asking how to specify the output file for each query's results? If so, please can you let us know which version of SQL you are using (MySQL, Postgres, Oracle, SQLServer, etc), as this is likely to vary between different SQLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on comments, see if this returns what you're looking for.

If there are no records in the table the result is `No Input File`

When records are present, each row is evaluated with the `CASE` statement.

```
--drop table table1

create table table1
(SubjectArea varchar(255)
, SrcFileName varchar(255))

insert into table1
select 'UaqaFacetsPvs','somefilename1.txt'
union select 'UaqaFacetsRjct','somefilename2.txt'
union select null,null
union select null,'somefilename2.txt'

IF EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM table1 WHERE SubjectArea in ('UaqaFacetsRjct','UaqaFacetsPvs'))
    SELECT DISTINCT SrcFileName
     + ' - ' + 
     CASE SubjectArea 
        WHEN 'UaqaFacetsPvs' THEN 'FacetsPvsFile'
        WHEN 'UaqaFacetsRjct' THEN 'FacetsRjctFile'
        ELSE ''
      END AS Result
    FROM table1
    WHERE SubjectArea in ('UaqaFacetsRjct','UaqaFacetsPvs')
ELSE SELECT 'No input file' AS Result
```

This `IF` returns this:

```
Result
---------------------------------
somefilename1.txt - FacetsPvsFile
somefilename2.txt - FacetsRjctFile
```

Comment: Hi vinnie really appreciate your response but the rejects on top is nothing but the result from the two queries. i dont know what would be the .txt file or if there would be any file.

Comment: Can you provide the layout and data would be in table1 then?

Comment: sure vinnie, Here are both the queries and table is nothing but the ProcessControl in SSISlogs database. (dont have enough space so i put it in answer section) ONCE AGAIN THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP

Answer (score 0):

After all of struggle finally I figured this out. I took out the `IF..ELSE`. I created a temp table `INSERT INTO .. SELECT DISTINCT` in both the queries. So its like...

```
TRUNCATE TABLE #TEMP;

INSERT INTO #TEMP SELECT DISTINCT...... (Query 1);

INSERT INTO #TEMP SELECT DISTINCT...... (Query 2);

SELECT * FROM #TEMP;
```

Thanks all specially Vinnie. Appreciate your help Man.